# How to find and replace a word from 2 csv files

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to replace the column names of a csv file using an index csv files where the column names are given with a common id. I need to replace the column name with the id.

For example, key file is like this

```
    ids colnames
1   col1    val1
2   col2    val2
3   col3    val3
4   col4    val5
5   col5    val4
```

And my values file is somewhat like this

```
val1    val2    val3    val4    val5
a   2   2   2   2
b   3   3   3   3
c   4   4   4   4
d   5   5   5   5
e   6   6   6   6
f   7   7   7   7
g   8   8   8   8
```

And I need my output somewhat like this

```
col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
    a   2   2   2   2
    b   3   3   3   3
    c   4   4   4   4
    d   5   5   5   5
    e   6   6   6   6
    f   7   7   7   7
    g   8   8   8   8
```

I wrote a code to do it, but I am not able to replace the column names. Please help.

```
import csv, os
import pandas as pd

file1 = pd.read_csv("trial.csv", delimiter=",")
file2 = pd.read_csv("try.csv", delimiter=",")
out_csv = r"trialop.csv"
tempFile = open("fileop", 'w+' )

header1 = file1.columns
header2 = file2.columns

content = file1.ids
proid = file1.colnames

for ids in content:
    if ids in header2:
        tempFile.write(header2.replace( header2, ids ))
```

It will be even more helpful if the output file can be a csv file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work.

```
with open('trial.csv.txt','r') as file:
    trial_raw = file.read()
trial = trial_raw.split('\n')
del trial[0]

new_columns = []
for col in trial:
    col1= col.split(',')
    new_columns.append(col1[0])


with open('try.csv.txt','r') as file:
    try_raw = file.read()
try1 = try_raw.split('\n')
del try1[0]

new_columns_str= ''

for cols in new_columns:
    if new_columns.index(cols)!=len(new_columns)-1:
        new_columns_str+=cols+','
    else:
        new_columns_str+=cols

#Inserts the new columns
try1.insert(0,new_columns_str)

new_file = ''

for line in try1:
    if try1.index(line)!=len(try1)-1:
        new_file+=line+'\n'
    else:
        new_file+=line
with open('trialop.csv','w')as file:
    file.write(new_file)
```

Comment: I tried it but I end up getting the column names numbered and not the way I want. And also my actual data file is 500MB+ so I cannot rely on this as it will consume a lot of memory. Any other better and efficient method? Maybe using pandas? Thank you